# JSlider with two pointers

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jslider

I want to give a user a convenient way to enter range from swing gui.
What can I use? A perfect option would be a slider with two pointers.

Comment: do you meaning two knobs in one JSlider ???

Comment: then have to search for RangeSlider, maybe I posted similair code here too

Comment: yes, also if JSlider has interval 0-100 one point e.g. 10 and the second one points on 33. So the range 10-33 is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SwingX](http://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases) has JXMultiThumbSlider which is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Btw, this implementation of RangeSlider is more simple for me, but swingx stuff should work somehow too, if your implement Renderer first.

http://ernienotes.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/creating-a-java-swing-range-slider/